# How to generate the same value for two different paths in spec?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'm trying to learn how to use [`overrides`](https://github.com/clojure/spec.alpha/blob/b2b5db433cad9f1ad56bd28f584136cef2bae73e/src/main/clojure/clojure/spec/alpha.clj#L286) with `s/gen`.

I have a `::parent` map which contains a `::child` map. Both parent and child have keys in common. The **requirement** is that the keys have the same value between parent and child, e.g. `{:a 1 :b 2 :child {:a 1 :b 2}`. I know this seems redundant, but the problem domain requires it.

The code below generates examples, but the **requirement** above is not met.

Is there a way to use the same generated value in two locations?

```clj
(ns blah
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
            [clojure.spec.gen.alpha :as gen])) 

(s/def ::a (s/int-in 1 5))
(s/def ::b (s/int-in 1 6))

(s/def ::child
  (s/keys :req-un [::a ::b]))

(defn- parent-gen []
  (let [a #(s/gen ::a)
        b #(s/gen ::b)]
    (s/gen ::parent-nogen
           ; overrides map follows
           {::a a ::b b
            ::child #(s/gen ::child
                            ; another overrides map
                            {::a a ::b b})))

(s/def ::parent-nogen
  (s/keys :req-un [::a ::b ::child]))

(s/def ::parent
  (s/with-gen ::parent-nogen parent-gen))

(gen/sample (s/gen ::parent))
```

Comment: I removed the custom generator, wrote a checking function and incorporated it into the parent spec using `s/and`. Its works if hammered enough. Still would be interesting to know if there's an answer to the question as asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with test.check's `fmap`:

```
(s/def ::a (s/int-in 1 5))
(s/def ::b (s/int-in 1 6))
(s/def ::child (s/keys :req-un [::a ::b]))
(s/def ::parent (s/keys :req-un [::a ::b ::child]))
(gen/sample
  (s/gen ::parent
         {::parent ;; override default gen with fmap'd version
          #(gen/fmap
            (fn [{:keys [a b child] :as p}]
              (assoc p :child (assoc child :a a :b b)))
            (s/gen ::parent))}))
=>
({:a 1, :b 2, :child {:a 1, :b 2}}
 {:a 2, :b 2, :child {:a 2, :b 2}}
 {:a 1, :b 1, :child {:a 1, :b 1}}
 {:a 3, :b 2, :child {:a 3, :b 2}}
 {:a 2, :b 4, :child {:a 2, :b 4}}
 {:a 4, :b 4, :child {:a 4, :b 4}}
 {:a 3, :b 3, :child {:a 3, :b 3}}
 {:a 4, :b 4, :child {:a 4, :b 4}}
 {:a 3, :b 4, :child {:a 3, :b 4}}
 {:a 3, :b 4, :child {:a 3, :b 4}})
```

`fmap` takes a function `f` and a generator `gen`, and returns a new generator that applies `f` to every value generated from `gen`. Here we pass it the default generator for `::parent`, and a function that takes those parent maps and copies the appropriate keys into the `:child` map.

If you want this spec to enforce that equality (besides just generation), you'll need to add an `s/and` to the `::parent` spec with a predicate to check that:

```
(s/def ::parent
  (s/and (s/keys :req-un [::a ::b ::child])
         #(= (select-keys % [:a :b])
             (select-keys (:child %) [:a :b]))))
```

Edit: here's another way to do the same thing with `gen/let` that allows for a more "natural" `let`-like syntax:

```
(gen/sample
  (gen/let [{:keys [a b] :as parent} (s/gen ::parent)
            child (s/gen ::child)]
    (assoc parent :child (assoc child :a a :b b))))
```

Comment: Brilliant! (I think `gen/let` is directly from `clojure.test.check.generators`, not in `clojure.spec.gen.alpha`. Is that right?)

Comment: @JeremyField that's right, spec dynamically loads/aliases (some of) test.check so that spec dependents only need test.check dependency if they _use_ it: https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_project_setup